# Why didn't LMT stock spike and NOC dip in 1990 due to the F-22 raptor competition?

Tags: equities, correlation

Disclaimer, I am a newbie at finance!

I have been tracking the NOC and LMT stock prices and I have a few questions.

1. Both companies seem to be moving together in terms of stock prices. I would expect a differentiation when one gets a contract and the other does not.
2. In the case of the F-22 raptor competition in the 1990s LMT won but there seems to be no spike in its stock price and most importantly no dip in NOC that lost the competition. How can that be explained?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the precise date when the competition result was publicly announced? ("sometime in 1990" isn't enough).

Comment: I have no idea, so I googled and found a couple of pages describing the competing aircraft: https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/196040/AFmuseum/lockheed-martin-f-22a-raptor/ , https://www.afmc.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/2919261/flashback-northrop-yf-23-black-widow-ii/ . My guess would be that perhaps the decision did not surprise the markets much, but was already priced in.?